# Efficiently handling duplicates in a Python list

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, grouping, graph-algorithm

I'm looking to compactly represent duplicates in a Python list / 1D numpy array. For instance, say we have

```
 x = np.array([1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0])
```

this array has several duplicate elements, that can be represented with a

```
 group_id = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1])
```

so that all duplicates in a given cluster are found with `x[group_id==<some_id>]`.

The list of duplicate pairs can be efficiently computed with sorting,

```
s_idx = np.argsort(x)
diff_idx = np.nonzero(x[s_idx[:-1]] == x[s_idx[1:]])[0]
```

where the pair `s_idx[diff_idx]` <-> `s_idx[diff_idx+1]` correspond to the indices in the original array that are duplicates. 
(here `array([1, 2, 3])` <-> `array([2, 5, 4])`).

However, I'm not sure how to efficiently calculate `cluster_id` from this linkage information for large arrays sizes (`N > 10⁶`).

**Edit:** as suggested by **@Chris_Rands**, this can indeed be done with `itertools.groupby`,

```
 import numpy as np
 import itertools

 def get_group_id(x):
     group_id = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype='int')
     for i, j in  itertools.groupby(x):
         j_el = next(j)
         group_id[x==j_el] = i
     return group_id
```

however the scaling appears to be **O(n^2)**, and this would not scale to my use case (`N > 10⁶`),

```
  for N in [50000, 100000, 200000]:
      %time _ = get_group_id(np.random.randint(0, N, size=N))

  CPU times: total: 1.53 s
  CPU times: total: 5.83 s
  CPU times: total: 23.9 s
```

and I belive using the duplicate linkage information would be more efficient as computing duplicate pairs for `N=200000` takes just 6.44 µs in comparison.

Comment: have you looked at `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: what about using `np.bincount` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks for the suggestion, I just did, see my edit above.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I do not fully agree with your edits, "clustering" might not be indeed the right term here but "handling duplicates" in the title is too generic. I oversimplified my original problem, and while the answers address this post (and I will accept the first one), they do not address my actual problem. I'm using the simhash algorithm to find near duplicates in a list (elements that differ by less than k bytes), so I cannot actually use `np.unique`: the algorithm returns the list of duplicate pairs (as explained above) and I'm looking to construct the `cluster_id` from that information.

Comment: You could try to be more precise on how the desired output is defined (e.g. enumerate by first occurrence?) and why you need to change the integers in the first place, and *why* you can't use `np.unique`

Comment: Also if speed is really crucial, don't use Python (or at least, rewrite crucial parts like this in Cython).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
In [13]: x = np.array([1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0])

In [14]: values, cluster_id = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)

In [15]: values
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 3])

In [16]: cluster_id
Out[16]: array([1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0])
```

(The cluster IDs are assigned in the order of the sorted unique values, not in the order of a value's first appearance in the input.)

Locations of the items in cluster 0:

```
In [22]: cid = 0

In [23]: values[cid]
Out[23]: 0

In [24]: (cluster_id == cid).nonzero()[0]
Out[24]: array([1, 2, 5])
```

Comment: Aww, I missed the `return_inverse=True` argument to `np.unique`; this works and scales great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [`np.unique`](https://numeric.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to keep the order according to the first appearance of a number -

```
unq, first_idx, ID = np.unique(x,return_index=1,return_inverse=1)
out = first_idx.argsort().argsort()[ID]
```

Sample run -

```
In [173]: x
Out[173]: array([1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 9, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 4, 8])

In [174]: unq, first_idx, ID = np.unique(x,return_index=1,return_inverse=1)

In [175]: first_idx.argsort().argsort()[ID]
Out[175]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't looking to preserve the first appearance number but I appreciate the answer.